# Numpy Array Division - unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, division

I defined the following numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
numpy_array = np.array([[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1], [-1,2,2,2,-1], [-1,2,8,2,-1], [-1,2,2,2,-1], [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]])
```

Now I wanted to divide the whole array by 8:

```
numpy_array /= np.float(8.0)
```

I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'
```

I hope someone has a hint for me, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: That doesn't look like a regular array. Each element of it is a list and not an array.

Comment: Is the final element in the list meant to have 6 items, the others have only 5?

Comment: @njoose you are right, this is an error!

Answer (score 4):

The array has a list of the incorrect size, the final list is incorrect.

if you want to keep the data as an `int`, you can use `numpy_array = np.divide(numpy_array, 8.0)`, otherwise see MSeifert's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatly your inner lists aren't the same size so numpy creates an object array:

```
>>> numpy_array
array([[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [-1, 2, 2, 2, -1], [-1, 2, 8, 2, -1],
       [-1, 2, 2, 2, -1], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]], dtype=object)
```

You should try to avoid `object` arrays because they might not behave like expected and of course they are slower. If you need different sized inner lists, you should mask elements:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> numpy_array = np.array([[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, np.nan], 
...                         [-1, 2, 2, 2,-1, np.nan], 
...                         [-1, 2, 8, 2,-1, np.nan], 
...                         [-1, 2, 2, 2,-1, np.nan], 
...                         [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]])
>>> numpy_array = np.ma.array(numpy_array, mask=np.isnan(numpy_array))
>>> numpy_array /= 8.0
>>> numpy_array
masked_array(data =
 [[-0.125 -0.125 -0.125 -0.125 -0.125 --]
 [-0.125 0.25 0.25 0.25 -0.125 --]
 [-0.125 0.25 1.0 0.25 -0.125 --]
 [-0.125 0.25 0.25 0.25 -0.125 --]
 [-0.125 -0.125 -0.125 -0.125 -0.125 -0.125]],
             mask =
 [[False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Also you need to be careful with inplace-operations because they don't change the `dtype`, so when you have an integer array and in-place-divide it with a float you'll still have an integer array (with truncated results) or get an exception:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> arr /= 8.0
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'l') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
```

Create a `float` array instead (or cast to `float` or just do a normal division `arr = arr / 8.0`):

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=float)
>>> arr /= 8.0
>>> arr
array([ 0.125,  0.25 ,  0.375])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! Actually I made an mistake, the last list had 6 elements, but should have had only 5 (Thanks to njoose for pointing out). Applying your approached worked!

Comment: @Max Okay, I thought that was intentional. But if that was just an oversight you only need to remove the unnecessary element from the last list :)