# How to use numpy to calculate mean and standard deviation of an irregular shaped array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that has many samples in it of varying length

```
Samples = np.array([[1001, 1002, 1003],
                    ... ,
                    [1001, 1002]])
```

I want to (elementwise) subtract the mean of the array then divide by the standard deviation of the array. Something like:

```
newSamples = (Samples-np.mean(Samples))/np.std(Samples)
```

Except that doesn't work for irregular shaped arrays,

np.mean(Samples) causes

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

due to what I assume to be it having set a static size for each axis and then when it encounters a different sized sample it can't handle it. What is an approach to solve this using numpy?

example input:

```
Sample = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                   [1, 2]])
```

After subtracting by the mean and then dividing by standard deviation:

```
Sample = array([[-1.06904497,  0.26726124,  1.60356745], 
                [-1.06904497,  0.26726124]])
```

Comment: Your "array" is not one of numbers but of list objects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293329/numpy-array-division-unsupported-operand-types-for-list-and-float

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy Array Division - unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293329/numpy-array-division-unsupported-operand-types-for-list-and-float)

Comment: Do you want to use the mean/standard deviation of the whole array (Samples) or just of each element of Samples?

Comment: What's your expected output of (Samples-np.mean(Samples))/np.std(Samples)?

Comment: Will add an edit to the question to demonstrate example input and output

Comment: Don't use ragged arrays.  Make a list of arrays if you need to and loop

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel  I can't add padding of np.nan to this array and still get an accurate mean and standard deviation.

Comment: @MichaelHackman: Are you sure about your output ? I obtain: `[array([-1.06904497,  0.26726124,  1.60356745]), array([-1.06904497,  0.26726124])]`

Comment: @Nuageux I am subtracting the overall mean from each element in the array, then dividing by the overall standard deviation

Comment: @MichaelHackman yes you can get an accurate [mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) and [std](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanstd.html#numpy.nanstd) with nan arrays.

Comment: @Nuageux Yes, you were right, I forgot to change the code I was working with. Edited to reflect the changes.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo That is a very handy tip, didn't know about nanmean

Comment: If you are looking for a vectorized method, get a regular array filled with NaNs for those empty places from this [**`post`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40571482/3293881) and then simply use nan funcs : `(a-np.nanmean(a))/np.nanstd(a)`, where `a` is the NaN filled array. It has some setup overhead, so performance gain if any would depend on the data format and size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@MichaelHackman (following the comment remark).
That's weird because when I compute the overall std and mean then apply it, I obtain different result (see code below).

```
import numpy as np

Samples = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                   [1, 2]])
c = np.hstack(Samples)  # Will gives [1,2,3,1,2]
mean, std = np.mean(c), np.std(c)
newSamples = np.asarray([(np.array(xi)-mean)/std for xi in Samples])
print newSamples
# [array([-1.06904497,  0.26726124,  1.60356745]), array([-1.06904497,  0.26726124])]
```

*edit*: Add np.asarray(), put `mean,std` computation outside loop following Imanol Luengo's excellent comments (Thanks!)

Comment: Yes, you are correct! I forgot to change the code I was working with, but I have edited the question to reflect the changes. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Oh hold on, I am definitely getting different results than you still

Comment: @MichaelHackman Can you update the question while I'm checking manually?

Comment: Well, that's exactly the same output that the one I got :)

Comment: Another minor comment, just for efficiency issues: precalculate `avg = np.mean(c)` and `std = np.std(c)` outside of the list comprehension to avoid multiple calculations. Is useful specially with large arrays.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo Excellent remark, I don't know where my mind was for not seeing this! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Don't make ragged arrays.  Just don't.  `Numpy` can't do much with them, and any code you might make for them will always be unreliable and slow because `numpy` doesn't work that way.  It turns them into `object` dtypes:

```
Sample
array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]], dtype=object)
```

Which almost no `numpy` functions work on.  In this case those objects are `list` objects, which makes your code even more confusing as you either have to switch between `list` and `ndarray` methods, or stick to list-safe `numpy` methods.  This a recipe for disaster as anyone noodling around with the code later (even yourself if you forget) will be dancing in a minefield.

There's two things you can do with your data to make things work better:

First method is to index and flatten.

```
i = np.cumsum(np.array([len(x) for x in Sample]))
flat_sample = np.hstack(Sample)
```

This preserves the index of the end of each sample in `i`, while keeping the sample as a 1D array

The other method is to pad one dimension with `np.nan` and use `nan`-safe functions

```
m = np.array([len(x) for x in Sample]).max()
nan_sample = np.array([x + [np.nan] * (m - len(x)) for x in Sample])
```

So to do your calculations, you can use `flat_sample` and do similar to above:

```
new_flat_sample = (flat_sample - np.mean(flat_sample)) / np.std(flat_sample)
```

and use `i` to recreate your original array (or list of arrays, which I recommend:, see `np.split`).

```
new_list_sample = np.split(new_flat_sample, i[:-1])

[array([-1.06904497,  0.26726124,  1.60356745]),
 array([-1.06904497,  0.26726124])]
```

Or use `nan_sample`, but you will need to replace `np.mean` and `np.std` with `np.nanmean` and `np.nanstd`

```
new_nan_sample = (nan_sample - np.nanmean(nan_sample)) / np.nanstd(nan_sample)

array([[-1.06904497,  0.26726124,  1.60356745],
       [-1.06904497,  0.26726124,         nan]])
```